# How to give proper name for a relation in DB using typeorm?

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I am using TypeORM with PostgreSQL. I want to give some proper name for a relation (foreign-key key/primary-key) in DB side.

Below is some part of my type-orm entity

```
  @Index()
  @ManyToOne(() => AccountYear)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'account_year_id' })
  accountYear: AccountYear;

  @Index()
  @ManyToOne(() => Supplier)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'supplier_id' })
  supplier: Supplier;
```

Below is the postgreSQL's screen showing some GUID as foreign key name.

[image]

**Is there any way to give the proper name for a relation in DB using typeorm?**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you cannot do it through annotations, but there is a `namingStrategy` in the configuration options.  [This issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1355#issuecomment-660013778) has an example and links to [sample code](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/tree/master/sample/sample12-custom-naming-strategy).

Putting the code here for completeness in case these links go bad:

options in main app:

```
const options: ConnectionOptions = {
    type: "mysql",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3306,
    username: "root",
    password: "admin",
    database: "test",
    synchronize: true,
    namingStrategy: new CustomNamingStrategy(),
    entities: [Post]
};

createConnection(options).then(connection => { ... })
```

CustomNamingStrategy:

```
import {NamingStrategyInterface} from "";
import {DefaultNamingStrategy} from "";
import {snakeCase} from "";

export class CustomNamingStrategy extends DefaultNamingStrategy implements NamingStrategyInterface {

    tableName(targetName: string, userSpecifiedName: string): string {
        return userSpecifiedName ? userSpecifiedName : snakeCase(targetName);
    }

    columnName(propertyName: string, customName: string, embeddedPrefixes: string[]): string {
        return snakeCase(embeddedPrefixes.concat(customName ? customName : propertyName).join("_"));
    }

    columnNameCustomized(customName: string): string {
        return customName;
    }

    relationName(propertyName: string): string {
        return snakeCase(propertyName);
    }

}
```